# Dynamic variable with dynamic results in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

dubdub_count=3

```
for (( i=1; i<=${dubdub_count}; i++ )); do
  my_apps --ammount=${dubdub_count}
done
```

The program will return the IP Address
Example results

```
app1=10.10.10.1
app2=10.10.10.2
app3=10.10.10.3
```

Theses ip addresses will be used in other service. I am creating a apiserver.sh bash script to run apiserver command like this bellow

```
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub=http://${app1},http://${app2},http://{app3} --master
```

I want my apiserver.sh has ability to add dynamic results from my_apps results.

If i change `dubdub_count=3` to be `dubdub_count=4`
My script must be able to be run like this

```
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub=http://10.10.10.1:8080,http://10.10.10.2:8080,http://10.10.10.3,http://10.10.10.4 --master
```

If i change `dubdub_count=3` to be `dubdub_count=5`
My script must be able to be run like this

```
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub=http://10.10.10.1:8080,http://10.10.10.2:8080,http://10.10.10.3:8080,http://10.10.10.4:8080,http://10.10.10.5:8080 --master
```

Summary issue is how to add my_app results automatically into `--dubdub` parameters ? If my_app returns 6 IP Address, my --dubdub will get 6 IP Address too. I don't need to edit my bash script manually.

I have read `dynamic var in bash` as keyword in stackoverflow, still i can't find out the best solution for that.
Should i suggest the my_apps developer to change the results method ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get where is the issue for you. At which part are you failing?

Comment: @pLumo added some explanation. Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `http://` and `:8080` using `sed`, then `paste -sd,` to put them together separated by comma:

```bsh
urllist=$(
  for ... done \
  | cut -d= -f2 \
  | sed 's#.*#http://&:8080#' \
  | paste -sd, -
) # output: http://10.10.10.1:8080,http://10.10.10.2:8080,http://10.10.10.3:8080
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub="$urllist" --master
```

Or do the `cut`, `sed` and `paste` part all together in one `awk` command:

```bsh
urllist=$(
  for ... done \
  | awk -F= 'NR>1{printf ","};{printf "http://"$2":8080"}'
) # output: http://10.10.10.1:8080,http://10.10.10.2:8080,http://10.10.10.3:8080
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub="$iplist" --master
```

Comment: The first answer is more legit... but yeah... i think that regex is so perfect.

Comment: Do you know the right title for this question ? tell me some suggestion pls :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can put that first loop into its own script or into a shell function called `my_apps_loop` (or you can just insert it in place for the `my_apps_loop` call below).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

urls=()

# Create URLs
while IFS='=' read -r app ip; do
    urls+=( "http://$ip:8080" )
done < <(my_apps_loop)

(
    IFS=','

    # Call apiserver with generated URLs
    /usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub="${urls[*]}" --master
)
```

This would loop over the output of `my_apps_loop` (which would output the lines with `app1=...` etc.) reading the `appN` part into `$app` and the string after the `=` into `$ip`.

For each line read, the `$ip` bit is prepended with the string `http://`, suffixed with `:8080`, and inserted into the array `urls`.

The subshell at the end calls `apiserver`.  The `--dubdub` option gets its value from the `urls` array with the values of the array concatenated into a single string delimited by commas.

Comment: All good but OP was edited to add port `8080` to every IP address output. Also why the parentheses as in `( IFS=',' [...])`, in the last part of your script ?  You cannot mean to execute the parentheses' content in a subshell (would not work as is anyway), nor is there any precedence in a list of operations at stake here ...

Comment: @Cbhihe Thanks for the heads up about the port (now fixed). The parentheses at the end limits the scope of setting `IFS` to a comma to only the commands within that subshell.  This is used to delimit the values in `urls`. What would not work?

Comment: Just a syntax issue for me... I was under the _impression_ that subshells in bash are created with following syntax `(list)` when using parentheses (no space, no tabs after opening or before closing). So I would favor either `(IFS=','; /usr/local/....)` or even `IFS=',' && /usr/local/...` with no parentheses since the latter (branching conditionned on process exit status) does create a subshell in which you can set IFS independently of your calling env..

Comment: @Cbhihe The newlines don't matter, and I wanted to add a comment before the actual command. Using `IFS=',' && command` does not start a subshell and will not limit the scope of `IFS` in any way, so it would set `IFS` for the rest of the script, which may not be wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with:

```
$ seq -f "http://10.10.10.%g:8080" 1 3
http://10.10.10.1:8080
http://10.10.10.2:8080
http://10.10.10.3:8080
```

You can then turn that into a function:

```
$ ddcount() { seq -f "http://10.10.10.%g:8080" "$@" ; }
$ ddcount 5 7
http://10.10.10.5:8080
http://10.10.10.6:8080
http://10.10.10.7:8080
```

(note: because this just passes all arguments to the `seq` command, the FIRST argument is optional and defaults to 1.  i.e. `seq 3` is the same as `seq 1 3`, and `ddcount 3` is the same as `ddcount 1 3`.  You can also specify an increment if one is needed. See `man seq` for details)

Combine this with another function to join arguments using a delimiter (e.g. a comma):

```
$ join_by() { local d=$1; shift; printf '%s' "$1"; shift; printf '%s' "${@/#/$d}"; }
```

This is modelled on the perl `join()` function, but named `join_by` so it doesn't conflict with the `join` command.   The first argument is the delimiter.  Remaining arguments are the data to be joined.

```
$ join_by , $(ddcount 1 3)
http://10.10.10.1:8080,http://10.10.10.2:8080,http://10.10.10.3:8080
```

Note: Do not double-quote the `$(ddcount 1 3)` function call - you **want** the string it returns to be word-split into multiple items, not treated as just one long string.  Compare the output of the above command with `join_by , "$(ddcount 1 3)"` to see the difference.

Finally, putting all of that together:

```
start=1; stop=3
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub="$(join_by , $(ddcount "$start" "$stop"))" --master
```

or

```
dd="$(join_by , $(ddcount "$start" "$stop"))"
/usr/local/bin/apiserver --dubdub="$dd" --master
```

Comment: Why not simply: `http_format=$(seq -s, -f "http://10.10.10.%g:8080" 1 3)` instead of a comparatively complicated `join` function ?   (On bash v5.0.9 here.) -- Also I would not advise anyone to use `dd` as a variable name. Something "unfortunate" could happen.

Comment: because a) i wanted to write an answer that showed how to break down a problem into smaller tasks and solve them individually, and b) because a join_by function is extremely useful and everyone should know how to write one.

Comment: I don't have any superstitions about variable names.